# Should 'the' be used in this title?

Tags: grammar, differences

BBC has a documentary titled [Ancient Rome: The Rise and Fall of an Empire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0864944/). History channel has a documentary titled similarly but without the 'the': [Rome: Rise and Fall of an Empire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1221224/).  Are both correct?  What's the subtle difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical, and there isn’t much difference between them. The first refers specifically to the actual rise and fall of Rome. The second refers to rise and fall more generally, and sounds more sensational.

Comment: I prefer the first version for purely logical reasons. The second version starts with "Rome:", a particular empire about which information to be given is introduced by a colon, followed by a more general statement that apparently could apply to any one empire, given the absence of definite article.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct - they make sense and clearly explain the theme of the programme.

The title is an allusion to Gibbon's "The History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire" one of the first 'modern' history books. The history channel was probably just looking for a shorter snappier version of the title to fit in listing magazines and electronic programme guides.